# Sorting a list based on another list which is sorted in steps

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist

I'm trying to sort list `B` based on the sorting of list `A`. The tricky part is that the sorting of list `A` is done in steps.
I've tried zipping the lists but I just can't get it to work.

The sorting of list `A` is done like this:

```
steps = [0, 1, 3, 5]
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
A = [['X', 'Y'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y']

for i in range(len(steps)-1):
    A[steps[i]:steps[i + 1]] = sorted(A[steps[i]:steps[i + 1]], key = len, reverse=True)
```

The following is happening:

sublist 0 in `A` gets sorted based on the length in reversed order, then sublists 1,2 then 3,4 and finally 5,6.

Comment: I don't see a list `A` in your example code, and list `C` in the code is not mentioned in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: One more suggestion. It would be nice if you included the output that you expect. The loop and the sublists make it difficult to digest what you are trying to do. Sample output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip to sort the lists, you just need a key function that can interpret the pairs. Then once you sort the pairs you can 'unzip' them using zip

```py
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
A = [['X', 'Y'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y']]
def lenRight(pair):
    return len(pair[1])
C = sorted(zip(B,A), key = lenRight)

B_sorted, A_sorted = zip(*C)
print(B_sorted)
print(A_sorted)
```

This will output:

```
('B', 'E', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'D', 'F')
(['X'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

EDIT:

I understand now,

```py
steps = [1, 3, 5]
B = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
A = [['X', 'Y'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y']]

lastStep = 0
sortedLists = []

def lenRight(pair):
        return len(pair[1])

for step in steps:
    C = sorted(zip(B[lastStep:lastStep+step],A[lastStep:lastStep+step]), key = lenRight, reverse = True)

    B_sorted, A_sorted = zip(*C)
    sortedLists.append((A_sorted, B_sorted))

    lastStep = step

for pair in sortedLists:
    A_sort, B_sort = pair
    print(A_sort, B_sort)
```

Outputs:

```
(['X', 'Y'],) ('A',)
(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X']) ('C', 'D', 'B')
(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['X', 'Y'], ['X']) ('D', 'F', 'G', 'E')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It works as you described but it misses the fact that the lists need to be sorted in steps. For example: the first 3 elements by their lenght then the next 4 by their lenght then the next 3 and so on.

Comment: I see what you mean now and updated the answer with one that sorts the sublists

Comment: Thank you again, this seems to work fine! Is it possible to do it without the seperate "def lenRight"? I tried changing the key to "lambda: len(pair[1])" , but can't figure it out.

Comment: You almost have it with the lambda, but you need an input to the lambda, so do: ```lambda pair : len(pair[1])```

Comment: Aha I see, brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the objects in `A` are hashable and unique:

1. Zip `A` and `B` together into list `C` and set that list off to the side.
2. Sort `A` using your mysterious step based algorithm. Don't worry about `B` or `C`
3. When the sort finishes, build a reverse lookup dictionary of `A` items to where the sort algorithm put them.
4. Use that reverse lookup and the zipped list to sort `B`.

```
A = [29, 42, 17]
B = ['bravo', 'charlie', 'alpha']
C = list(zip(A, B))
A.sort() # replace with your mystery sorter
lookup = {a:index for (index, a) in enumerate(A)}

for  (a, b) in C:
    index = lookup[a]
    B[index] = b

print(A)
print(B)
```

```
#output
[17, 29, 42]
['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']
```

The cost of building `C`, building the lookup dictionary, and organizing `B` at the end are all O(n)

Disclaimer: not a fan of writing back into `B`. Would prefer to write to a new list that has been properly sized.

**Update:** The code above only works if there are no duplicates in A. The snippet of code below handles duplicates by attaching a piece of uniqueness (the original index). Although this works, the approach is just too convoluted. You might as well sort the zip of A and B together, which is described in the other answer.

```
A = [29, 42, 29, 17]
B = ['bravo1', 'charlie', 'bravo2', 'alpha']
A2 = [(index, a) for index,a in enumerate(A)]
C = list(zip(A, B))
A2.sort(key=lambda t : t[1] ) # replace with your mystery sorter, which has to deal with tuples now
A = [a for (_, a) in A2]
lookup = {t:index for (index, t) in enumerate(A2)}

for  original_index, (a, b) in enumerate(C):
    new_index = lookup[original_index, a]
    B[new_index] = b

print(A)
print(B)
```

```
#output
[17, 29, 29, 42]
['alpha', 'bravo1', 'bravo2', 'charlie']
```

For completeness, the code below is what I would really do if I had to deal with duplicates in A. This is essentially the other answer that was posted.

```
A = [29, 42, 29, 17]
B = ['bravo1', 'charlie', 'bravo2', 'alpha']
C = list(zip(A, B))
C.sort(key=lambda t : t[0] ) # replace with your mystery sorter, which has to deal with a zip of A and B together
[A, B] = zip(*C)

print(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: Hi, I can't really get it to work unfortunately. Question: does this method, with lookup, work if the items in lists are not unique?

Comment: @Fred_Alb, For this to work, the items in A need to either be unique, or made unique by attaching some piece of data. I will edit to clarify.